# Java Spring dependency injection not working

Tags: java, spring

I am very new to Java Spring and I tried to set up 2 classes and a Test for one of them. That is my project structure:

[image]

Here is the code for the classes:

```java
@Component
public class Box {

    private Item item;

    @Autowired
    public Box(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class BoxConfig {}
```

```java
@Component
public class Item {}
```

And here is the code of the JUnit Test I wrote in the BoxTest class:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BoxConfig.class})
public class BoxTest {

    @Autowired
    Box box;

    @Test
    public void BoxTest1() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(box.getItem());
    }
}
```

My Expectation was, that Spring automatically injects a box object into the box attribute of the Test, but the box attribute ist always null so I keep getting a NullReferenceException. Does someone know why it is not properly initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoxTest needs to be included in Spring configuration somehow.
E.g. using `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` would help.

You can look at other options in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit-jupiter).

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. But what exactly is the problem when I don't have that line?

Comment: Without that line Spring doesn't know that you have a class that needs injection. Similarly how if you had a non-test class without e.g. Component annotation but an Autowired field inside. That field would be always set to default value (unless of course you would create a bean in another way).